# how django handle binary post data?

Tags: python, django, post, django-models, binary

[image: post data]

the user_logo file is actually a img data ,

how can I save this img to a django model ?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/QhTbZpmGPe0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `'user_logo'` is [a JPEG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) encoded in `base16/hex` (except the prefix `'<'`)

```
>>> 'ffd8ffe000104a4649460001010100'.decode('hex')
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00'
```

You could use [ContentFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#additional-methods-on-files-attached-to-objects) to store this sort of data

```
obj.image.save(filename, ContentFile(the_decoded_content))
```

Also, better to ask the dude implementing client-side whether he could post in `multipart/form-data`, if so the `user_logo` could be easily accessed through `request.FILES`...and less request body

Answer (score 2):

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_uploads')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commercial
```

**views.py**

```
def add_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
return direct_to_template(request, 'page.html', {
    'form': ImageForm()
})
```

**page.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.image}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule you don't want to store images in databases.  Django's [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) and [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) load the data off the disk.

**Edit:** just noticed the title had to do with post data.  Check out the article on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/)